# JSON_VALUE does not take dynamic JSON path

Tags: sql-server, json-value

I am using SQL Server 2016.

While this works fine:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(N'[{"FieldName":"xyz"}]', N'strict $[0]."FieldName"')
```

This retruns an error:

```
DECLARE @x nvarchar(100)
SET @x =N'0'

SELECT JSON_VALUE(N'[{"FieldName":"xyz"}]', N'strict $['+@x+']."FieldName"')

SELECT JSON_VALUE(N'[{"FieldName":"xyz"}]', N'strict $[sql:variable(@x)]."FieldName"')
```

Error:

> The argument 2 of the "JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY" must be a string
> literal.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The `sql:variable()` syntax is not supported in any version; this only works for XML queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use SQL Server 2017+. As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments), in *SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and in Azure SQL Database, you can provide a variable as the value of path*. But even then, I don't think that `N'strict $[sql:variable(@x)]."FieldName"'` is a valid `path` expresison for a `JSON_VALUE()` call.

Working example for SQL Server 2017+:

```
DECLARE @x nvarchar(100)
SET @x = N'0'

SELECT JSON_VALUE(N'[{"FieldName":"xyz"}]', N'strict $[' + @x + ']."FieldName"')
```

For SQL Server 2016 you may try the following:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(100) = N'[{"FieldName":"xyz"}]'
DECLARE @x nvarchar(100) = N'0'

SELECT JSON_VALUE([value], '$.FieldName')
FROM OPENJSON(@json) j1
WHERE [key] = @x
```