# JSON_Value error: The argument 2 of the "JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY" must be a string literal

Tags: c#, json, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to use JSON_VALUE and SQL Server 2016. I am having to build my SQL query dynamically though.

JSON:

```
{"pageId":"9","moduleId":"6","moduleType":"Pages"}
```

Here is my error:

Argument 2 of the "JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY" must be a string literal.

```
            var sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            // start the initial select query...
            sb.Append("SELECT * FROM dbo.FileSystemItems WHERE ");

            int counter = 0;
            foreach (var item in metadata)
            {
                // only add an AND if we are NOT the first record...
                if (counter != 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(" AND ");
                }

                // setup our json path and value items...
                string pathParam = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "jsonPathParam{0}", counter);
                string valueParam = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "jsonPathValue{0}", counter);

                sb.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "JSON_VALUE(FileMetadata, @{0}) = @{1}", pathParam, valueParam);

                // add in our parameters to assist with sql injection
                sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter(pathParam, string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "N'$.{0}'", item.Key)));
                sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter(valueParam, string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "N'{0}'", item.Value)));

                counter++;
            }

            return await BIContext.FileSystemItems
                          .Where(x => x.ModuleId == moduleId)
                          .FromSql(sb.ToString(), sqlParams.ToArray())
                          .Select(s => new FileSystemItemJsonDTO
                          {
                              FileId = s.FileId,
                              FileName = s.FileName,
                              FileType = s.FileType,
                              LastWriteTime = s.LastWriteTime,
                              FileSystemItemDataId = s.FileSystemItemDataId,
                              ModuleId = moduleId,
                              FileMetadata = s.FileMetadata,
                              FileSize = s.FileSize
                          })
                          .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Here is the generated StringBuilder result as the SQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.FileSystemItems WHERE JSON_VALUE(FileMetadata, @jsonPathParam0) = @jsonPathValue0 AND JSON_VALUE(FileMetadata, @jsonPathParam1) = @jsonPathValue1
```

I've tried the items from this post:

[JSON_VALUE does not take dynamic JSON path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64114850/json-value-does-not-take-dynamic-json-path)

but it still gives me the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

I need to support 2016 and 2017.

**UPDATE:**

I found this as well: https://dapper-tutorial.net/knowledge-base/46860751/csharp-dapper-using-json-value-for-sql-server-2016 ->

This says it might not be possible?

Then I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

and it says my version is supported:

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU15-GDR) (KB4583461) - 13.0.5865.1 (X64)   Oct 31 2020 02:43:57   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0  (Build 19041: )

**UPDATE 2:**

After the response below, I found the code that works on SQL server 2016 and SQL server 2017.

I'm just trying to understand IF/why it protects against SQL Injection because I am not parameterized the 2nd argument of `JSON_VALUE()`

```
        public async Task<IList<FileSystemItemJsonDTO>> GetFileSystemItems(int moduleId, IDictionary<string, string> metadata)
        {
            var sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            // start the initial select query...
            sb.Append("SELECT * FROM dbo.FileSystemItems WHERE ");

            int counter = 0;
            foreach (var item in metadata)
            {
                // only add an AND if we are NOT the first record...
                if (counter != 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(" AND ");
                }

                // setup our json path and value items...
                string valueParam = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "jsonPathValue{0}", counter);

                // 2nd item for JSON_VALUE has to be string literal for SQL server 2016
                sb.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "JSON_VALUE(FileMetadata, '$.{0}') = @{1}", item.Key, valueParam);

                // add in our parameters to assist with sql injection
                sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter(valueParam, string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}", item.Value)));

                counter++;
            }

            return await BIContext.FileSystemItems
                          .Where(x => x.ModuleId == moduleId)
                          .FromSql(sb.ToString(), sqlParams.ToArray())
                          .Select(s => new FileSystemItemJsonDTO
                          {
                              FileId = s.FileId,
                              FileName = s.FileName,
                              FileType = s.FileType,
                              LastWriteTime = s.LastWriteTime,
                              FileSystemItemDataId = s.FileSystemItemDataId,
                              ModuleId = moduleId,
                              FileMetadata = s.FileMetadata,
                              FileSize = s.FileSize
                          })
                          .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

Comment: Since the SQL is *already* built dynamically, the actual literals can be used (guarding for injection in this special case). Depending on the JSON format itself, it might be possible to rewrite such using OPENJSON and the resulting set.

Comment: @user2864740: so I do not need to do the @ and add the parameters to `    .FromSql(sb.ToString())`

Comment: @user2864740: I think it just needs to be this: `
                sb.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "JSON_VALUE(FileMetadata, '$.{0}') = @{1}", item.Key, valueParam);` and it will protect against SQL injection because I have at least one parameterized even though the 2nd item for the `JSON_VALUE()` is string literal?

Comment: The *resulting* SQL needs the literal SQL literal strings in those positions, per the error. View the generated output string to verify what the exact content of the SQL text sent to the server is and update it accordingly. *When embedding values directly into SQL text, extra care must be taken to avoid potential SQL injection as Parameters are **not** used for those values*. If all the keys are *simple*, I recommend OPENJSON, as shown in the current answer.

Comment: As for above, imagine that item.Key is: `foo'); delete .. —`

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no “standard” method for literal string escaping in ADO.NET. However, limiting, or folding, keys to all ASCII alpha-numeric would likely be suitable here: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@user2864740](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864740/user2864740), we can rewrite this using a Table-Valued Parameter and `OPENJSON`.

First create a table type, I suggest you think carefully about the exact column types and lengths:

```sql
CREATE TYPE Metadata TABLE (jsonKey nvarchar(100) PRIMARY KEY, jsonValue nvarchar(1000) NOT NULL);
```

And the query uses relational division:

```sql
SELECT *    -- Preferably don't use select *, specify necessary columns instead
FROM dbo.FileSystemItems
WHERE moduleId = @moduleId
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT m.jsonKey, m.jsonValue
    FROM @metadata m
    EXCEPT
    SELECT j.[key], j.[value]
    FROM OPENJSON(FileMetadata) j
);
```

This basically says: there must not be any metadata requirements which **DON'T** have a matching key/value pair.

Another, sometimes more efficient version, of the same thing:

```sql
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM @metadata m
    LEFT JOIN OPENJSON(FileMetadata) j
        ON j.[key] = m.jsonKey AND j.[value] = m.jsonValue
    HAVING COUNT(j.[Key]) = COUNT(*)
);
```

This says: if we add up all metadatas which have matching key/values, they must be the same as the number of all metadatas.

Were you to want an `OR` semantic, a simple join would suffice:

```sql
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM @metadata m
    JOIN OPENJSON(FileMetadata) j
        ON j.[key] = m.jsonKey AND j.[value] = m.jsonValue
);
```

---

Now lets' query this in C#. Add in the query above in the correct place.

I tend to make the TVP parameter construction into an extension method, I will leave that to you.

```cs
public async Task<IList<FileSystemItemJsonDTO>> GetFileSystemItems(int moduleId, IDictionary<string, string> metadata)
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("jsonKey", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("jsonValue", typeof(string));
    foreach (var item in metadata)
        table.Add(item.Key, item.Value);

    var params = new[] {
        new SqlParameter("@metadata", SqlDbType.Structured)
        {
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
            TypeName = "dbo.Metadata",
            Value = table
        },
        new SqlParameter("@moduleId", SqlDbType.Int){Value = moduleId}
    };
    const string query = @"
SELECT ...
";
    return await BIContext.FileSystemItems
                          .FromSql(MyQuery, params)
                          .Select(s => new FileSystemItemJsonDTO
                          {
                              FileId = s.FileId,
                              FileName = s.FileName,
                              FileType = s.FileType,
                              LastWriteTime = s.LastWriteTime,
                              FileSystemItemDataId = s.FileSystemItemDataId,
                              ModuleId = moduleId,
                              FileMetadata = s.FileMetadata,
                              FileSize = s.FileSize
                          })
                          .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: I'll check out this solution and respond if we go with it.